# qooxdoo and javascript screen recorders

Tags: screen, qooxdoo, recorder

Hi:
I'm trying to use an javascript screen recorder in my qooxdoo app (efexam.com/app), but user clicks are captured by qooxdoo and the screen recorder (smt2) don't get them. Just get and record the hovered elements...
Any advice?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

the qooxdoo event system is catching all events and does fire own events on the DOM nodes. This is root cause why "smt2" is getting no events.

Is there an API which can be used to send events? Maybe it is possible to *forward* the events of the qooxdoo event layer to this API. Just a thought ...

Comment: hi: thanks for your answer. Some clues about programming with qooxdoo event system, how to catch EVERY mouse event without kill app performance and how to forward these events passing absolute coordinates to main browser objects again, so smt2 or whatever library can catch them?